# Why do we cast to Comparable in TreeMap

Tags: java, collections

I am learning `Collections` in Java, and came across the below code in the `TreeMap` API,

```
 if (key == null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
            Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
            do {
                parent = t;
                cmp = k.compareTo(t.key);
                if (cmp < 0)
                    t = t.left;
                else if (cmp > 0)
                    t = t.right;
                else
                    return t.setValue(value);
            } while (t != null);
```

Why do we need to cast to `Comparable` in the first place? Since the `key` is already implementing `Comparable` and having the `compare()` overriden. Why can't we call `key.compare(t.key)` ?

Key is implementing Comparable.

Comment: How was key defined?

Comment: Keys in a TreeSet don't necessarily implement Comparable (you can provide a Comparator in the TreeSet constructor).

Comment: Too bad you only included part of the code. `key` is defined as `Object`, so it's not implementing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TreeMap` documentation provides the following information:

> A Red-Black tree based {@link NavigableMap} implementation. The map is
>   sorted according to the {@linkplain Comparable natural ordering} of
>   its keys, or by a {@link Comparator} provided at map creation time,
>   depending on which constructor is used.

The following two `TreeMap` constructors (there are more, but the same rule applies) also apply to that specific rule. The first one assumes that the key is natually `Comparable` (and each inserted key is required to do) while the second one provides the possibility to supply a custom `Comparator`.

```
public TreeMap() {
    comparator = null;
}

public TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator) {
    this.comparator = comparator;
}
```

The determine which behaviour should be used, the implementation frequently validates if the `Comparator` has been initialized.

```
final int compare(Object k1, Object k2) {
    return comparator == null ? ((Comparable<? super K>)k1).compareTo((K)k2)
        : comparator.compare((K)k1, (K)k2);
}
```

So your following assumption does not apply:

> Since the key is already implementing Comparable and having the
>   compare() overriden.

The key `K` of the `Map` can be any type and is not limited to be `Comparable`. This provides more flexibility, since sometimes you cannot make a class mutually comparable (for example, if it comes from a third party library) or a class logically does not have a natural ordering. I would recommend to read the documentation of both `Comparable` and `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

`key` is not declared as implementing `Comparable`.

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
```

It cannot be declared as Comparable in `put()` because it is possible to put keys in TreeMap, which do not implement Comparable - you must provide the comparator then. This is shown just above the code which you quoted.

```
        // split comparator and comparable paths
        Comparator<? super K> cpr = comparator;
        if (cpr != null) {
            do {
                parent = t;
                cmp = cpr.compare(key, t.key);
                if (cmp < 0)
                    t = t.left;
                else if (cmp > 0)
                    t = t.right;
                else
                    return t.setValue(value);
            } while (t != null);
        }
        else {
            if (key == null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
            do {
                parent = t;
                cmp = k.compareTo(t.key);
                if (cmp < 0)
                    t = t.left;
                else if (cmp > 0)
                    t = t.right;
                else
                    return t.setValue(value);
            } while (t != null);
        }
```